# What's wrong with this PHP vote script?

Tags: php, sql-server

This is my vote script for my game: http://pastebin.com/p8DF7SVK

Just the lines where the check function is:

```
$num_rows = $adb->doQuery('SELECT ' . ACCOUNT . ' FROM ' . ACCOUNT_TABLE . ' WHERE DateDiff(dd, CreateDate, GetDate()) <= 1 AND ' . ACCOUNT . ' = ?', $_SESSION[ACCOUNT]);
      if ($num_rows != 0)
      {
        DEBUG_LOG(__METHOD__, 'Account only just registered! Account = %s, ip = %s', $_SESSION[ACCOUNT], $this->site->getRemoteIP());
        header('Location: ' . $url);
        return;
      }
```

but somehow everytime someone wants to vote. It always says in the logs: `Account only just registered!` and it doesn't add the points for voting .. so, something wrong should be with this check but I am not able to understand what exactly. I've tried to set the account to be 1 month old, 1 year old and etc but still everything the same. They vote, the check shows in the log that it's just new account (no matter if the account is 1 year old even) and it doesn't add the points.

Check line 123-129, where the check function is. Will be much appreciated if you let me know what's wrong with this check for new accounts.

Comment: Could you please add the code to the question?

Comment: It's big code. Will mess the whole page ..

Comment: Then perhaps just the lines that you think are incorrect, plus a few more for context?

Comment: more something for [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), no?

Comment: Added the check function to the question above.

Comment: do a `var_dump` of `$num_rows` and see what you get back. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @NMALKO - thank you. How are you accessing the database? `doQuery` is apparently a MongoDB function, but you've tagged the question as SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL Server 2005 .. strange is that I strongly believe it worked a while ago but not anymore .. without any changes. I might not be correct but that's what I remember. So, yeah. I'm on MSSQL Server 2005. UPDATE2: Also, my whole website is written like that, so that's not the case. It's something other ...

Comment: @NMALKO - can you get any errors from your doQuery function? Can you echo out your generated SQL and see if it works when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: Hmmm. I am thinking something .. in the query there isn't `*` before `FROM` .. could it because of that ?

Comment: @NMALKO - is it just 'SELECT FROM'? the `ACCOUNT` isn't defined anywhere? If so, then yes - your query will be failing.

Comment: I'm just being stupid. Fixed it on my own. I've been using different tables and etc
Thank you a lot guys for your time.

Comment: @NMALKO - you can add your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: Just so you know, questions nearly always should have source code, otherwise they are difficult/impossible to answer, and will just be closed. I've rolled back your last edit to one that contains some code - once you get an answer, it is good to leave the question as it is, so other people may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using totally different tables and etc. It's fixed.
Thank you a lot guys for your time and great support on stackoverflow.
It's been always really appreciated.